# problem with mapping preg_replace to images

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$imageMap=preg_replace('/([a-z ])/', '<img src="egypt/$1.png" />', $input);
```

Which works for `a-z` but when it comes to a `'space'` being inputted, it looks for `' .png'` which i have in the folder but it says:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /egypt/ .png was not found on this server.
```

I noticed that in the url it displayed `/egypt/%20.png`, so when i put another image called `'%20.png'` it still said not found on the server.

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not name files like *space*.png - many systems just trims (cuts the space on beginig) name of the file and it is really messy then. Naming file like this is not correct and causes problems like this.

Comment: any suggestions on how i get around this then?

Comment: Indeed. A space as a filename is a complete recipe for disaster. Use a sane name instead.

Comment: Yes, chose anything, but not space, for example _ (it will be a little bit messy, but system-correct).

Comment: ok understood, thanks for the advice, but how then shall i alter my code, because when a user inputs a space, a space must seperate the users words inputted. because the coding takes anything inc. spaces and puts them into the image coding.

Comment: You can forbid inputing these names. But, if the file just has to be named like this, you can make list of files (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and than work with it.